# Android Vuforia Native SDK camera direction Front

Tags: android, sdk, native, augmented-reality, vuforia

Unable to change camera direction using Vuforia Native SDK.

I am changing

```
vuforiaAppSession.startAR(CameraDevice.CAMERA_DIRECTION.CAMERA_DIRECTION_DEFAULT);
```

at `ImageTargets.java` inside Vuforia sample app. The result I am getting with front camera is just black screen.

Here is the error code:

```
VuforiaSamples E/ImageTargets: Unable to open camera device: 2
    com.vuforia.samples.SampleApplication.SampleApplicationException: Unable to open camera device: 2
        at com.vuforia.samples.SampleApplication.SampleApplicationSession.startCameraAndTrackers(SampleApplicationSession.java:153)
        at com.vuforia.samples.SampleApplication.SampleApplicationSession.access$900(SampleApplicationSession.java:31)
        at com.vuforia.samples.SampleApplication.SampleApplicationSession$StartVuforiaTask.doInBackground(SampleApplicationSession.java:623)
        at com.vuforia.samples.SampleApplication.SampleApplicationSession$StartVuforiaTask.doInBackground(SampleApplicationSession.java:604)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Not able to find some more specific information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, **Vuforia** has deprecated this option.

See [CameraDevice.CAMERA_DIRECTION Class Reference](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/reference/java/classcom_1_1vuforia_1_1CameraDevice_1_1CAMERA__DIRECTION.html). Same for C++ headers:

> ```
> enum CAMERA_DIRECTION
> { 
>     CAMERA_DIRECTION_DEFAULT,   ///< Default camera direction (device-specific,
>                                 ///  usually maps to back camera) (DEPRECATED)
>     CAMERA_DIRECTION_BACK,      ///< The camera is facing in the opposite direction as the screen (DEPRECATED)
>     CAMERA_DIRECTION_FRONT,     ///< The camera is facing in the same direction as the screen. (DEPRECATED)
>                                 ///< Notes: This enum is deprecated.
>                                 ///< Front camera support will be removed in a future Vuforia release.
>                                 ///< The front camera is not compatible with DeviceTracker
>                                 ///< nor with SmartTerrain.
> };
> ```